# Understanding Shell, Conductor, Main Window concept in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro, mahapps.metro

I'm having a hard time to grasp the **Shell** vs **Main Window** vs **"which conductor to use"** concept, even after reading the docs about [Screen and Conductors](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition).

Suppose I'm creating an app that has a menu toolbar that almost always will be visible (but not always).

- Each menu shows a different View in the container space.
- When some event occurs, the app should show a completely different View (not even the menu should be visible).
- There will be a settings button in the titlebar (Mahapps.metro): [image]

  - When settings is clicked, a flyout (or popup) should be shown (not inside the container space).

(1) So, **MetroWindow** would be a **Conductor.Collection.AllActive**, because it will hold flyout/popup and the main container, and both can be activated at the same time?

(2) Also, the (1) would hold the *screen* which is activated from some event? (screen which will not have menu as I described earlier).

(3) **Main container** would be a **Conductor.Collection.One**, because it will hold the *screens* activated from menu, and only one can be activated at a time?

Am I in the right path? Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out.

**ShellView** is built with **MetroWindow**. **ShellViewModel** is a simple `Conductor<IContainer>`.

This viewmodel will manage *flyouts* as well which *IContainer* is current visible. Moreover, this viewmodel will manage *any buttons* that are in the *Mahapps.metro titlebar*.

Each **IContainer** could be any type of Conductor (Collection.One or Collection.AllActive). This way, an *IContainer* can either display a menu or not; it's entirely up to it.

To sum up and answer my own question:

1. No. MetroWindow will be the ShellView, which has ShellViewModel, which inherits from Conductor.
2. ShellViewModel will active any IContainer. So yes, when an event is raised, ShellViewModel will listen and active the appropriated viewmodel.
3. No. There are no Main Container; only the ShellView.

Comment: Could you handle an example using OneActive and the ShellView as a centralizer? Thanks..

Comment: *OneActive* usually means you're using `TabControl` or `ListBox`, because you have *n* items but only one is active at a time.